# WebElement Visible and sometimes not Visible

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

The element sometimes become visible and sometimes does not become visible.
Also the element is not in the DOM.
How to handle this situation using Selenium Webdriver?

Comment: Put yourself in the shoes of somebody who knows nothing about what you're doing (that's us). Now ask yourself, is this enough information for anyone to provide an answer to your question? You'll find that the answer is "No". Which means that you need to add *a lot* more detail to your question.

Comment: How can the element be visible but not be in the DOM?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1st you can wait for the element to be visible on DOM

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated("YOUR LOcator")));
```

You can also check if the element is present on DOM or not. Use below code for same

```
  if (driver.findElements("YOUR LOCATOR").size() != 0) {  
            driver.findElement(YOUR LOCATOR).click();  
            System.out.println("element exists");     
        }  
  else{
           System.out.println("element is not exists");     
      }
```

Hope it will help you :)